# How to find the limit function of $f_n:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_n(x)=nxe^{-nx}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

And proof that this is indeed the limit with the $e-\delta$ definition.
Also show on what subintervals the convergence is uniform. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are interested in the limit as $n\to \infty$, so the proof statement would be: for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists an $N$ so that $|f_n(x) -f(x)|\lt \epsilon$ for all $n \gt N$.

The limit function $f(x)=0$ in this case.  $f_n(x)$ is maximum at $x=\frac{1}{n}$, where $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{e}$.  For a specific $x$, let $N=\frac{\epsilon}{x}$, so $f_N(x)=\epsilon e^{-\epsilon}\lt \epsilon$. However, because $N$ is dependent on $x$, it cannot be uniform on the entire $R_+$ interval.
On the other hand for any interval $(x_0,\infty)$ where $x_0 \gt 0$, we can get uniform convergence on that interval, because $N$ for $x_0$ is more than enough for $x\gt x_0$.